# How to get the binary code behind ASCII (C#)

Tags: c#, binary, ascii

I'm trying to find out how to convert input to a console, into binary; how can such a conversion be made in C#?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  It is not clear what you want to ask.  Give an example if possible.

Comment: Say someone enters the letter 'a' when the console hits a ReadLine()
How could I convert that 'a' into binary code?

Comment: It's still unclear. What does 'a' mean in binary? Does it mean 97 or 10?

Comment: How is it unclear? The Binary code, Base2.

Comment: You want the ASCII code of that character, into an integer variable?  Just type cast it into an int.  E.g. `int code = (int) ch;`

Comment: everything is binary, the rest is just an illusion. ;) now, what exactly do you want to do with that 'binary' data? write it somewhere?

Comment: I just need to know how to get the binary code, I know how to write it somewhere.

Comment: Simple question: if user inputs 'a' what binary code/number you are expecting to have?

Comment: Okay, I don't know binary myself, so I had to use an online converter.. Anyway, I'm guessing it gave me the correct answer; if the user inputs 'a' the output would be '01100001'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
```

Note that the encoding used by the console isn't actually ASCII... you should probably use `Console.InputEncoding` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`

To get the binary representation of each byte, you can use `Convert.ToString`:

```
foreach(byte b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2));
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, what 'using' do I need for this?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: @James Litewski, isn't it what you want? If not, you should probably clarify the question...

Comment: Oh, I get it... you want the binary representation of the ASCII value, right ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was goin for.

Comment: Why is it printing the last three values on separate line?

Answer (score 0):

An individual character can be implicitly converted to an integer.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28VS.80%29.aspx).  If you want to convert a whole string then Thomas's suggestion makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET's build in BinaryReader/BinaryWriter classes.